# Is a change in colorspace needed when comparing colors only evaluated by the computer?

Tags: opencv, colors

I am confused about the need to change color space for color comparison. I have read about delta E, the Lab format, and I do understand that comparisons in the RGB color space will not seem appropriate to the human eye. However, my program uses a linear color scale to calculate velocity, from a color flow Doppler signal. It takes the mean color of a sample region and compares it to the colors of the scale to find its nearest neighbor using Euclidian distance. I do that entirely in the BGR (OpenCV) color space, as the example image below:

[image: example signal image]

Here, I obtain seemingly correct velocity values for each color circle, but is it only by chance, or **is my assumption correct that since the color comparisons take place internally, it does not matter what color space I am in?**

Comment: Its never "needed" but if you want to compare color similarities it might be much easier to define similarity in HSL/HSV colorspace for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you searchind for nearest neighbour, and operate with 3D points (in color space) it does not matter what color space you choose, they will only be displayed in different ways.

Answer (score 1):

Comparison of colour is not straight forward. You need to decide what defines a colour being close to another and then pick the most appropriate colour space to support that.

For example, working in HSL will give you an easy way to assess colours based upon the hue. This is fine if you are happy to disregard, or at least reduce the relevance of saturation and luminance.

If on the other hand, you want a point change in saturation to be a relevant as a point change in hue, working in RGB or perhaps CMYK would be more appropriate. Measuring the distance by plotting the channels as three axis and then creating a distance between the two colours. This has the downside that a 10 point shift in saturation has the same measured difference as a 10 point shift in hue, which visually will not make that much sense as the perceived difference will not be equivalent to the mathematical.

And that brings in another consideration. The human eye is more sensitive to colour variance around different colours. Green for example, takes more variation to be noticeable than magentas. All down to evolution but may have a bearing in your representation.

Personally I tend to work with RGB as it is needed for visual display, but most commonly I will arrange colours by hue so keep a conversion handy to HSL/ HSB.